# Are I/O streams really thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I wrote a program that writes random numbers to one file in the first thread, and another thread reads them from there and writes to another file those that are prime numbers. The third thread is needed to stop/start the work. I read that I/O threads are thread-safe. Since writing to a single shared resource is thread-safe, what could be the problem?
**Output:** always correct record in `numbers.log`, sometimes no record in `numbers_prime.log` when there are prime numbers, sometimes they are all written.

---

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>


using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::atomic_int ITER_NUMBERS = 30;
std::atomic_bool _var = false;
bool ret() { return _var; }
std::atomic_bool _var_log = false;
bool ret_log() { return _var_log; }
std::condition_variable cv;
std::condition_variable cv_log;
std::mutex              mtx;
std::mutex mt;
std::atomic<int> count{0};
std::atomic<bool> _FL = 1;
int MIN = 100;
int MAX = 200;

bool is_empty(std::ifstream& pFile) // function that checks if the file is empty
{
    return pFile.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof();
}


bool isPrime(int n) // function that checks if the number is prime
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return false;
    
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    
    return true;
}


void Log(int min, int max) { // function that generates random numbers and writes them to a file numbers.log
    std::string str;
    std::ofstream log;
    std::random_device seed;
    std::mt19937 gen{seed()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution dist{min, max};
    log.open("numbers.log", std::ios_base::trunc);
    for (int i = 0; i < ITER_NUMBERS; ++i, ++count) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulm(mtx);
        cv.wait(ulm,ret);
        str = std::to_string(dist(gen)) + '\n';
        log.write(str.c_str(), str.length());
        log.flush();
        _var_log = true;
        cv_log.notify_one();
        //_var_log = false;
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(500000));
        
    }
    log.close();
    _var_log = true;
    cv_log.notify_one();
    _FL = 0;
}




void printCheck() { // Checking function to start/stop printing
    
    std::cout << "Log to file? [y/n]\n";
    while (_FL) {
        char input;
        std::cin >> input;
        std::cin.clear();
        if (input == 'y') {
            _var = true;
            cv.notify_one();
        }
        if (input == 'n') {
            _var = false;
        }
    }
}

void primeLog() { // a function that reads files from numbers.log and writes prime numbers to numbers_prime.log
    std::unique_lock ul(mt);
    int number = 0;
    std::ifstream in("numbers.log");
    std::ofstream out("numbers_prime.log", std::ios_base::trunc);
    if (is_empty(in)) {
        cv_log.wait(ul, ret_log);
    }
    int oldCount{};
    for (int i = 0; i < ITER_NUMBERS; ++i) {
        if (oldCount == count && count != ITER_NUMBERS) { // check if primeLog is faster than Log. If it is faster, then we wait to continue
            cv_log.wait(ul, ret_log);
            _var_log = false;
        }
        if (!in.eof()) {
            in >> number;
            if (isPrime(number)) {
                out << number;
                out << "\n";
            }
            oldCount = count;
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    std::thread t1(printCheck);
    std::thread t2(Log, MIN, MAX);
    std::thread t3(primeLog);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is you're misusing a state-based data store (a file) as an event-based message queue.  Way too many people abuse files this way, but as you've discovered, it's not reliable and it can never be reliable in general. Be glad you've discovered this early and not after you've had it appear to work for you. (This will probably generate a lot of "But it works for me!" comments, which would be more accurate if they were to say, "I haven't observed it to fail - yet.")

Comment: " I read that I/O threads are thread-safe." can you provide a reference or link?

Comment: What you are trying to do is called "read-behind-write".  It's such a perniciously ***HARD*** problem to solve, IBM even wrote an entire Redbook on it: https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp3945.pdf  They were so proud of that they had a full demo of it at the SC04 Supercomputer conference in Pittsburgh.

Comment: They should be thread safe, provided the platform is thread safe at the lower level.  There are many things in C++ that are thread safe themselves.  For example: a unique_ptr, but the thread safety of the object held by the unique_ptr is not part of the unique_ptr's guarantee — that object has to provide that thread safety guarantee itself.  Thread safety is not transitive.  Also, could be a compiler bug. (q.v. Andrew's explanation of where you went awry.)

Comment: @Eljay Even if the streams are thread-safe through-and-through, they're being misused here.  What does the read stream do when it hits EOF, for example?  It's a state-based stream, never looking for later events of more data getting written to the file to extend it.  In general, it can't even know about those events.

Comment: @Eljay In what way is `std::unique_ptr` threadsafe?

Comment: @PaulSanders • q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485874/4641116

Comment: @Eljay Yes, I saw that.  The answers there are mostly incorrect, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who wrote about read-behind-write, now I know more. But that was not the problem. The main problem was that if it was a new file, when calling `pFile.peek()` in the `is_empty` function, we permanently set the file flag to `eofbit`. Thus, until the end of the program `in.rdstate() == std::ios_base::eofbit`.

**Fix:** reset the flag state.

```cpp
if (is_empty(in)) {
cv_log.wait(ul, ret_log);
}
in.clear(); // reset state
```

There was also a problem with the peculiarity of reading/writing one file from different threads, though it was not the cause of my program error, but it led to another one.

Because if when I run the program again `primeLog()` opens `std::ifstream in("numbers.log")` for reading faster than `log.open("numbers.log", std::ios_base::trunc)`, then `in` will save old data into its buffer faster than `log.open` will erase them with the `std::ios_base::trunc` flag. Hence we will read and write to `numbers_prime.log` the old data.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the I/O stream thread safety. The shown code's logic is broken.

The shown code seems to follow a design pattern of breaking up a single logical algorithm into multiple pieces, and scattering them far and wide. This makes it more difficult to understand what it's doing. So let's rewrite a little bit of it, to make the logic more clear. In `primeLog` let's do this instead:

```
            cv_log.wait(ul, []{ return _var_log; });
            _var_log = false;
```

It's now more clear that this waits for `_var_log` to be set, before proceeding on its merry way. Once it is it gets immediately reset.

The code that follows reads ***exactly*** one number from the file, before looping back here. So, `primeLog`'s main loop will always handle exactly one number, on each iteration of the loop.

The problem now is very easy to see, once we head over to the other side, and do the same clarification:

```
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulm(mtx);
        cv.wait(ulm,[]){ return _var; });

        // Code that generates one number and writes it to the file

        _var_log = true;
        cv_log.notify_one();
```

Once `_var` is set to true, it remains true. This loops starts running full blast, iterating continuously. On each iteration of the loop it blindly sets `_var_log` to true and signals the other thread's condition variable.

C++ execution threads are completely independent of each other unless they are explicitly synchronize in some way.

Nothing is preventing this loop from running full blast, getting through its entire number range, before the other execution thread wakes up and decides to read the first number from the file. It'll do that, then go back and wait for its condition variable to be signaled again, for the next number. Its hopes and dreams of the 2nd number will be left unsatisfied.

On each iteration of the generating thread's loop the condition variable, for the other execution thread, gets signaled.

Condition variables are not semaphores. If nothing is waiting on a condition variable when it's signaled -- too bad. When some execution thread decides to wait on a condition variable, it may or may not be immediately woken up.

One of these two execution thread relies on it receiving a condition variable notification for every iteration of its loop.

The logic in the other execution thread fails to implement this guarantee. This may not be the only flaw, there might be others, subject to further analysis, this was just the most apparent logical flaw.

Comment: > On each iteration of the loop it blindly sets `_var_log` to `true` and signals the other thread's condition variable.
It's not blindly.
`_var_log = true` and `cv.notify_one()` is used to tell the other thread that we have incremented the loop and written a number, which means we can wake up the second thread, which can wait in case it processed its data faster than the first thread.

Comment: "Blindly" means that in the event that these carefully laid plans fall apart and `_var_log` is already true (because the other thread is not), the notification will be completely lost.

Comment: > Nothing is preventing this loop from running full blast, getting through its entire number range, before the other execution thread wakes up and decides to read the first number from the file. 

If the first thread has time to process its data even faster than the second starts, it will not go to sleep because `cv.wait(ulm,ret)` does not stop the thread if the `_var_log = true` predicate.

Comment: Now work your way through what happens if this happens ***twice***, beforehand.